# How do i convert hexadecimal value from string to int?

Tags: c#, string, hex

I have a string which typically is in the format : `"0xFF"`.
I'll trim it since there is a chance of whitespace.

How do i convert that into hex and convert "34" to decimal?
I know about `.Parse` but does this support hex characters when the string is `"0x123"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to strip the "0x" part, but this snippet works:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class StrToInt {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        string val = "FF";
        int num = Int32.Parse(val, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = int.Parse( "FF", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber );
MessageBox.Show( i.ToString() );  // displays 255
```

However, you will need to trim the leading "`0x`".